# Tripple dot operator and & operator on types explanation

Tags: typescript

Could someone please explain what does the following code snippet mean?

```js
const data: admin.auth.UserRecord & Partial<User> = {
   ...(await admin.auth().getUser(uid))
};
```

Comment: The three dots in JavaScript are spread / rest operator. I dont understand what bitwise and is doing there either. @downvoter: why the downvote?

Comment: `&` is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) and the `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: @CRice Could you please explain the meaning of the whole snippet? I think I have a rough idea of what the operators do now, i get that `...` can spread an array but what would it do on an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The `&` creates an intersection type.

An intersection type combines the properties of multiple types. [The TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) says, "an object of this type will have all members of all [the] types."

```
type UserRecord = {
  p1: string;
  p2: string;
};

type User = {
  p3: string;
  p4: string;
};

type UserRecordAndPartialUser = UserRecord & Partial<User>;

const userRecordAndPartialUser = {
  p1: "value1",
  p2: "value2",
  p3: "value3",
  p4: "value4"
};
```

## The `...` shallow clones the inner object to the outer object.

[The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) says it, "copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object."

```
const anotherUserRecordAndPartialUser = {
  ...userRecordAndPartialUser
};

console.log(anotherUserRecordAndPartialUser);
// {
//   p1: "value1",
//   p2: "value2",
//   p3: "value3",
//   p4: "value4"
// };
```